# transfer apps from iPhone 4S to iPad 3 using iTunes 10 on a PC

Tags: itunes, iphone, ipad

I have an iPad 3 and a iPhone 4S both logged in with the same Apple ID. I have downloaded about a dozen apps on my iPhone 4S and would like to transfer these over to my iPad 3.

I have connected my iPad to my PC with iTunes, however I cannot seem to find the setting that allows me to transfer the apps I have previously downloaded with this Apple ID to my iPad.

I am using iTunes 10.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to simply reinstall the apps, look for the `Apps` tab in the iPad sync settings on iTunes, tick the boxes of the apps you want to transfer. If you want to copy your save files, etc. then try the following.

***Note I haven't tried this***

When you reset your iPad or plug it in for the first time, it will ask you if you wish to restore from backup. Try choosing your iPhone 4S's backup if it's in the list.

Also, you can simply re-download from the app store on your iPad at no charge. Instead of a price tag, you will see an `Install` button.

Comment: When I go into iTunes > Devices (DeviceName) > Apps there are _no_ apps listed. I see an empty list on the right and a screenshot of my iPad (which has no apps, other than the default ones, installed). I believe there is a way to do it as i've heard of it being done before, and i'd rather not have to re-install all the apps i've installed on my iPhone. Can you elaborate on the setting(s) in iTunes to copy apps from one device to another?

Comment: There should be a list with checkboxes for all the apps that you installed on your iPhone. You do sync your iPhone with iTunes, right? Otherwise you'll have to use my third option (re-downloading them). iTunes only shows apps that have been copied to the computer.

Comment: I've never actually plugged the iPhone 4S into iTunes before, so no. I haven't sync'd with iTunes or a computer before. I'm doing it just now, shouldn't take too long, so hopefully this will fix it.

Comment: Ok, this should populate the app list, let me know if it works or otherwise. Try unplugging and reconnecting the iPad after the iPhone finishes synchronising, too (this might not be required).

Comment: OK, I didn't realise this, but some apps must have iPhone and iPad specific versions. They are all copied over now from my iPhone to my iPad, however _some_ apps are only showing in an iPhone-sized area in the centre of the screen (eBay and PayPal), whereas Facebook and Twitter apps are showing full screen as I would have expected. I can't imagine this is something I can control through settings, so I assume that i'll have to un-install and re-install from the App Store for the app that are not showing full screen.

Comment: Correct. You can actually run both apps side-by-side - if the developer doesn't release it as a universal app, and instead goes for an iPhone and an iPad version, they are two separate apps which can be installed separately. Also, if they didn't release an iPad version, you can use magnification mode (look for the little black circle saying `1x` or `2x` in the corner, push it, and the app expands to fill the screen).